# Select Best value from Text Field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to modify a query that is designed to populate our Online ordering site with the products it can sell.  I get my data from a view.  That veiw has all of the products for sale.  Sometimes products can be sold in kits of multiple products.  This kits have their own product ID but the veiw renders them with a record for each product so the data looks something like:

```
1 - item1 - item1desc - 1 - true
2 - item2 - item2desc - 1 - true
3 - item3 - item3desc - 1 - true
4 - item4 - item1desc - 3 - true
4 - item4 - item2desc - 3 - true
4 - item4 - item3desc - 3 - true
```

What i would like to see is

```
1 - item1 - item1desc - 1 - true
2 - item2 - item2desc - 1 - true
3 - item3 - item3desc - 1 - true
4 - item4 - kit includes item1desc, item2desc, item3desc - 3 - true
or
4 - item4 - kit - 1 - true
```

This is the query I have but it still returns 3 rows for a 3 item kit

```
SELECT [CustomerProductID]
      ,[CustomerProductName] AS CustomerItemName
      ,MAX([ProductDescription]) AS CustomerItemDescription
      ,COUNT([ProductNameID]) AS ProductCount
      ,[IsActive]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
  FROM [dbo].[vw_ProductList]
  where  CustomerID in (@tbl)
  GROUP BY [CustomerProductID], 
           [CustomerProductName], 
           [IsActive],
           [ModifiedDate]
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably `[ModifiedDate]` that is different for each row in a "3 item kit".

Remove `[ModifedDate]` from `GROUP BY` use `MAX([ModifedDate])` in the field list.